# How to make background of my app white?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to set background of my app to be white.

we can change it this way:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
```

But I want to be behind of the root grid also white.

In other way, How to change phone's theme to light behind my app?

Comment: Just set the `Background` of the next level up in the XAML to "White"?

Comment: there is no next level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [PhoneThemeManager](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/) library:

> The ThemeManager class provides static methods to be used during app
>   initialization to force the app's resources to appear as the Dark or
>   Light theme.

Just add `ThemeManager.ToLightTheme();` in the App constructor and your app will run like if the theme was Light (white background).

Comment: thanks @Olivier . it seems it is the only way for this. But I prefer not to use another external package. I looked at its source code and couldn't find how to do it myself https://github.com/jeffwilcox/wp-thememanager

Answer (score 0):

```
<PhonePage Background="White">
 ...
</PhonePage>
```